# Very simple scripting language (interpreter) in C

Tags: c, interpreter

I made very simple scripting language (interpreter) in C and now, I want to make my code better.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TRUE (1 == 1)
#define FALSE (1 == 0)

#define FUNCTION_COUNT 2
#define MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH 247
#define MAX_FUNCTION_ARG_LENGTH 127

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 2048

char *strr(char *str, char *output, int x, int y)
{
    int i;
    for (i = x + 1; i < y; i++)
    {
        output[i - (x + 1)] = str[i];
    }
    return output;
}

int is_string(char *str)
{
    if (str[0] == '"' & str[strlen(str) - 1] == '"')
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int is_sint(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] >= '0' & str[i] <= '9')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void lang_prints(char *s)
{
    char output[MAX_STRING_LENGTH] = "\0";
    if (is_string(s))
    {
        strr(s, output, 0, strlen(s) - 1);
        printf("%s\n", output);
    }
}

void lang_printi(int i)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    char function_names[FUNCTION_COUNT][MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH] = {
        "prints",
        "printi"
    };
    char input[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char output[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char function_name[MAX_FUNCTION_NAME_LENGTH] = "\0";
    char function_arg[MAX_FUNCTION_ARG_LENGTH] = "\0";
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    for (i = 0; i < FUNCTION_COUNT; i++)
    {
        strr(input, function_name, -1, strlen(function_names[i]));
        strr(input, function_arg, strlen(function_names[i]), strlen(input) - 1);
        if (strcmp(function_name, function_names[i]) == FALSE)
        {
            if (input[strlen(function_name)] == '(' & input[strlen(function_name) + strlen(function_arg) + 1] == ')')
            {
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        lang_prints(function_arg);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (is_sint(function_arg))
                        {
                            lang_printi(atoi(function_arg));
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Use `prints` to print string and `printi` to print integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful with choice of identifiers - names beginning with `str` are reserved for future library extension.  The identifiers beginning with `is_` are okay, because `_` isn't a lowercase letter.

This is needlessly verbose:

> ```
> if (str[0] == '"' & str[strlen(str) - 1] == '"')
> {
>     return TRUE;
> }
> else
> {
>     return FALSE;
> }
> ```

In general, the pattern `if (condition) return true; else return false;` can always be replaced by `return condition;`:

```
return str[0] == '"' && str[strlen(str) - 1] == '"';
```

Note that it's almost always better to use `&&` rather than `&` for combining logical values.

Similarly:

> ```
>     if (str[i] >= '0' & str[i] <= '9')
>     {
>         return TRUE;
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return FALSE;
>         break;
>     }
> ```

Here the `break` is useless, as that line cannot be reached.  And the enclosing `while` can be just `if`, since the function returns on its first iteration.  On the other hand, if the `while` condition is false, then the function returns *without a value* - you should get a compilation warning for that.

Also, there's no need to require that `str` point to a writeable string, so pass `const char*`.  And the test looks a lot like `isdigit()` (from `<ctype.h>`).

I suspect what's really meant is

```
int is_sint(const char *str)
{
    while (*str) {
        if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*str++)) { return 0; }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Danger!

> ```
>    scanf("%s", input);
> ```

This function takes no account of the capacity of `input`, and will happily overwrite data following it if the word it reads is longer.  Never use `%s` without a specific size for untrusted input.  In this code, it's unclear whether you want to read a single word anyway - it looks like a whole line is wanted, for which one should use `fgets()`.